# Unknown column in 'field list' error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to add array into DB table and I'm gettin this error: Unknown column 'clock' in 'field list' looking at the error it seems, that item name recognises as table field name... Here is the code:

```
include("includes/functions.php");

    function addItem($items) {
                    $count = 0;
                    $fields = '';

                    foreach($items as $laukelis => $verte) {
                    if ($count++ != 0) $fields .= ', ';
                    $laukelis = mysql_real_escape_string($laukelis);
                    $verte = mysql_real_escape_string($verte);
                    $fields .= "`$laukelis` = $verte";
                }

                     $query = "INSERT INTO `uzsakymai` SET $fields;";
                     $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                    }
    if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
        if($_POST["name"] && $_POST["surname"] && $_POST["address"] && $_POST["mail"] && $_POST["tel"] )
        {
            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $ppid=get_product_id($pid);
            $ppav=get_product_name($pid);
            $price=get_price($pid);
            $date=date('Y-m-d');
            $oid=mysql_insert_id();
            $cid=mysql_insert_id();
            ?>
            <?
            $items = array('id' => 'NULL',
                       'pirkejo_id' => $cid,
                    'prod_id' => $ppid,
                    'produkto_pav'=> $ppav,
                    'kaina' => $price,
                    'data' => $date
                    );

                    addItem($items)
                    ?>
<?                  
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you post the query that is ran?  That would be the most useful debugging information here.

Comment: AFAIK, `INSERT INTO \`uzsakymai\` SET $fields;` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your SQL will end up something like this

```
INSERT INTO `uzsakymai` SET `field1` = value `field2` = value2
```

This is not the proper syntax for INSERT. You are missing a comma between the fields.  Please look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) for how to insert data.

You can make your `$fields` var an array instead, and then use `implode(',', $fields);` to create the statement.

Comment: `INSERT` ... `SET` syntax works just fine in mysql. From the docs you linked *"The INSERT ... VALUES and INSERT ... SET forms of the statement insert rows based on explicitly specified values."*

Comment: Modified the answer to include what was missing. Thanks.